# Clarification about the JavaScript getCookie function?

Tags: javascript, cookies

The `getCookie`  function is first called in a checkCookie function as so:

```
var username=getCookie("username");
```

And this is the function:

```
function getCookie(c_name)
{
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
  {
  x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
  y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
  x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
  if (x==c_name)
    {
    return unescape(y);
    }
  }
}
```

I'm lost on what is happening overall.. why do you split on `;` , and mainly what is the reason for the the lines with `x` and `y`. [The source is here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp).  I appreciate any tips or advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cookies are always stored as: key1=value1;key2=value2

so the split on ; is to read all the key-value pairs into the ARRcookies variable.
Then, for each cookie, the key is read into  x, and the value into y

Comment: Thank You So Much Vijay - It's clicking with me now.

Answer (score 2):

The most effective way to get a cookie value is to use regular expressions.

```
function cookie_get(n){
  return (n=(document.cookie+';').match(new RegExp(n+'=.*;')))&&n[0].split(/=|;/)[1]
}
```